# Intersecting rectangles with Python

Tags: python, math, logic, conditional-statements, intersection

Given two rectangles r1 and r2 I try to test if the two intersect.
Why don't the following two functions produce the same output?

Function 1:

```
def separate_helper(r1, r2):
  r1_left, r1_top, r1_right, r1_bottom = r1
  r2_left, r2_top, r2_right, r2_bottom = r2

  if r1_right < r2_left:
    separate = True
  elif    r1_left > r2_right:
    separate = True
  elif r1_top > r2_bottom:
    separate = True
  elif r1_bottom < r2_top:
    separate = True
  elif contains(r1, r2):
    separate = False
  else:
    separate = False
  return separate
```

Function 2:

```
def separate_helper2(r1, r2):
  r1_left, r1_top, r1_right, r1_bottom = r1
  r2_left, r2_top, r2_right, r2_bottom = r2

  separate = r1_right < r2_left or \
    r1_left > r2_right or \
    r1_top > r2_bottom or \
    r1_bottom < r2_top or \
    not contains(r1, r2)
  return separate
```

Function to check if rectangle 1 contains rectangle 2:

```
def contains(r1, r2):
  r1_left, r1_top, r1_right, r1_bottom = r1
  r2_left, r2_top, r2_right, r2_bottom = r2
  return r1_right >= r2_right and  r1_left <= r2_left and  r1_top <= r2_top and  r1_bottom >= r2_bottom
```

Here's a test case that **fails**:

> assert separate_helper([29, 35, 53, 90], [23, 47, 90, 86]) == separate_helper2([29, 35, 53, 90], [23, 47, 90, 86])

It only fails when rectangle 1 contains rectangle 2, but I can't wrap my head around why.

**Edit:**

I'm using quickcheck for Python and nose to test the function. Here's the test code I'm using:

```
from qc import forall, lists, integers
from intersect import separate_helper, separate_helper2

@forall(tries=100, r1=lists(items=integers(), size=(4, 4)), r2=lists(items=integers(), size=(4, 4)))
def test_separate(r1, r2):
  assert separate_helper(r1, r2) == separate_helper2(r1, r2)
```

Comment: What do you mean fails? Crashes or just doesn't say they intersected?

Comment: @DiegoNolan If you run the code provided, you'll see that the equality at the end returns `False` but shouldn't.

Comment: @DiegoNolan The assertion fails. See updated question for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your first version:

```
elif contains(r1, r2):
  separate = False
else:
  separate = False
```

Assuming you get through all of the proper-intersection cases, this will return `False` whether `r1` contains `r2` or not.

But in your second version:

```
... or \
not contains(r1, r2)
```

This will return `False` is `r1` does not contain `r2`, but `True` otherwise.

So, they're doing different things in precisely the case "when rectangle 1 contains rectangle 2".

As a side question: why should `r1` containing `r2` return a different result from `r2` containing `r1`?

Comment: I think he just wants to check whether the **sides** of the rectangle intersects.

Comment: @Phoexo: I assume you're commenting on my side question. If you're right, there's no reason to check `contains` at all. If you're wrong, he needs to check `contains` in both directions. Either way, I can't see why he wants to check one way and not the other.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The full code contains both directions. I left it out intentionally to show a minimal failing test case.

Comment: @mre: No problem; I just wanted to make sure you hadn't overlooked something and, more importantly, I hadn't misunderstood your logic. (That's why it was just a side question.)